# Subscribe a plan in paypal through api

Tags: php, api, paypal

I want to subscribe a recurring plan in paypal through php as a webservice for mobile app,

First i want to know if this is possible or not, if yes then how and i just have an paypal email id of the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring

Comment: YOu can also use this script. https://www.formget.com/paypal-subscription/ and also thisw http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it with paypal email id
If you want to do subscription plan on any user you have to get their credit card details

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to do it?